# Core data only returning null

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a number of objects (NSManagedObject Subclass) which 'seem' to be created and saving correctly, however on reloading i can only get null from any of the variables within the objects.

The right number of objects are being saved, but none of the variables.

I've gone through the code several times, and I cant figure out if the problem is on the saving side or the loading side.

Would very much appreciate any thoughts!
Thanks in advance

```
//Create a route
- (CNSRoute *) createRoute
{

    CNSRoute *p = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CNSRoute" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [allRoutes addObject:p];
    //NSLog(@"Route: %@", p);
    return p;
}


//Load all routes from core data
- (void) loadAllRoutes
{
    NSLog(@"All Routes: %@", allRoutes);
    if (!allRoutes) {
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"CNSRoute"];
        [request setEntity:e];

        NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sd]];

        NSError *error;
        NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (!result) {
            [NSException raise:@"Fetch Failed" format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
        }
        NSLog(@"LOAD RESULT: %@", result);

        for (CNSRoute *route in result) {
            NSLog(@"Loading Route... %@", [route name]);
        }

        allRoutes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [allRoutes setArray:result];

        //NSLog(@"%@", allLocations);

    }
}

//Save context
- (BOOL)saveChanges
{
    NSError *err = nil;

    BOOL successful = [context save:&err];
    if (!successful) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR SAVING: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }

    return successful;
}

//Save when application enters background
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[CNSTravelController sharedStore] saveChanges];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mean when I close the app totally, but do not delete it. And yes, the context is saved when the app enters the background.

Comment: Yes this is iOS, for iPhone specifically. I'm stopping the app by pressing the home button on the simulator, not stopping the app in xcode.

Comment: I've been having this problem for days. I've tried stopping from XCode, from the 'kill' button on the multitask bar (after running without any debug session), and each time CoreData comes back with the correct number of entities, but null values for every attribute. (It must be something severely inaccurate about my understanding of CoreData, so I'm hoping for enlightenment as well.)

Comment: Can you include some of the implementation of your managed object subclass? Are you using the code generated automatically from the data model? If you're getting objects but no values, it sounds like you're getting your accessor methods wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific, which variables? Is name one of them that has nil value? Where and when do you set them and when and where are you reading them?